# How to get status of "Invoke-Expression", successful or failed?

Tags: powershell, exit-code

`Invoke-Expression` will return all the text of the command being invoked.

But how can I get the system return value of whether this command has been executed successfully or with a failure? In CMD I could use `%errorlevel%` to get external command execution state. What about PowerShell?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Normally you would use `$?` to inspect the status of the last statement executed:

```
PS C:\> Write-Output 123 | Out-Null; $?
True
PS C:\> Non-ExistingCmdlet 123 | Out-Null; $?
False
```

However, this won't work with `Invoke-Expression`, because even though a statement inside the expression passed to `Invoke-Expression` may fail, the `Invoke-Expression` call it self will have succeeded (ie. the expression, although invalid/non-functional was invoked none the less)

---

With `Invoke-Expression` you'll have to use try:

```
try {
    Invoke-Expression "Do-ErrorProneAction -Parameter $argument"
} catch {
    # error handling go here, $_ contains the error record
}
```

or a trap:

```
trap {
    # error handling goes here, $_ contains the error record
}
Invoke-Expression "More-ErrorProneActions"
```

---

The alternative is the append `";$?"` to the expression you want to invoke:

```
$Expr  = "Write-Host $SomeValue"
$Expr += ';$?'

$Success = Invoke-Expression $Expr
if(-not $Success){
    # seems to have failed
}
```

but relies on there not being any pipeline output

Comment: The 2nd line of the last example must be `$Expr += ';$?'` to avoid immediate interpretation of `$?`.

Comment: @letmaik nicely spotted, completely overlooked that

Answer (score 14):

If the executable called by `Invoke-Expression` supports it, you can use `$LASTEXITCODE`. You have to be careful about variable scoping, though.

```bsh
function foo 
{
    $global:LASTEXITCODE = 0 # Note the global prefix.
    Invoke-Expression "dotnet build xyz" # xyz is meaningless, to force nonzero exit code.
    Write-Host $LASTEXITCODE
}

foo
```

If you run it, the output will be:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: xyz
1
```

Observe the 1 at the end denoting nonzero exit code.

If you would forget the `global:` prefix, instead the output would have 0. I believe this is because your function-scoped definition of `LASTEXITCODE` would hide the globally-set one.

Answer (score 11):

In PowerShell you can evaluate execution status by inspecting the [automatic variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx)

```
$?
   Contains True if last operation succeeded and False otherwise.
```

and/or

```
$LASTEXITCODE
   Contains the exit code of the last Win32 executable execution.
```

The former is for PowerShell cmdlets, the latter for external commands (like `%errorlevel%` in batch scripts).

Does this help you?

Comment: `Invoke-Expression` always sets `$?` to `$true` no matter what, so `$?` won't help in that case.

Comment: `$?` works for my invocation like `&'path/to/exe' -params`, it returns `True` for exit code 0 and `False` for any other exit code.

Answer (score 9):

I found a simple way to do it, which keeps STDOUT in tact.

```
$Expr="MY EXPRESSION"
$Expr += '; $Success=$?'
Invoke-Expression $Expr
```

Success is now True or False, and all IO remains intact.

Comment: By golly even better if we substitute $LastExitCode instead of $?    Seems to work

Answer (score 0):

$LASTEXITCODE cannot be used with Invoke-Expression, as it will be zero regardless of whether the expression invoked succeeds or fails:

```
PS C:\Users\myUserAccount> touch temp.txt
PS C:\Users\myUserAccount> Invoke-Expression "Remove-Item .\temp.txt"
PS C:\Users\myUserAccount> echo $LASTEXITCODE
0

PS C:\Users\myUserAccount> Invoke-Expression "Remove-Item .\temp.txt"
Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\myUserAccount\temp.txt' because it does not 
exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item .\temp.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\myUserAccount\temp.txt:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

PS C:\Users\myUserAccount> echo $LASTEXITCODE
0
```

Comment: Partially incorrect. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55033231/986533).