# PowerShell run script from script: fail caller if called fails

Tags: powershell

I have `./main.ps1` that calls `./worker1.ps1` and `worker2.ps1` with parameters, lines from main.ps1:

```
# other stuff in main script
$args = @()
$args += ("-PARAM1", "$VAR1")
$args += ("-PARAM2", "$VAR2")
$worker1 = "./workers/worker1.ps1"
Invoke-Expression "$worker1 $args" -ErrorAction Stop
# other stuff in main script
$worker2 = "./workers/worker2.ps1"
Invoke-Expression "$worker2 $args" -ErrorAction Stop
```

If `worker1.ps1` fails it has `exit 1` line,
The problem is that even when `worker1.ps1` fails `worker2.ps1` is called by `main.ps1`

How could I avoid that and fail main script as soon as one of the called fails?

Comment: For one thing, **don't use** the self-defined variable name `$args`, because this is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#args)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get status of "Invoke-Expression", successful or failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348794/how-to-get-status-of-invoke-expression-successful-or-failed)

Answer (score 3):

- As [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) recommends, avoid the use of `$args` as a custom variable, because it is a so-called [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables?view=powershell-7.1#args) managed by PowerShell itself.
- [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).
- Use a [*hash table*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) rather than an *array* to formulate your arguments in a data structure, then use [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) to pass it.
- If your scripts use `exit` with a nonzero argument to signal failure, query the automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable to infer failure.

To put it all together:

```
# other stuff in main script

# Define the arguments as a *hashtable*.
$htArgs = @{
  PARAM1 = $VAR1
  PARAM2 = $VAR2
}

foreach ($worker in './workers/worker1.ps1', './workers/worker2.ps1') {
  & $worker @htArgs # Note the @ sigil for splatting
  if ($LASTEXITCODE) { Throw "$worker signaled failure via exit code $LASTEXITCODE" } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I didn't have your programs to work on I created a couple to duplicate what I thought you were saying, e.g. the Worker1.ps1 returned a 1 when it failed.

So the main program looks like this:

```
$TFArgs = @{ReturnCD = 0
            CallNumber = 1}


$RVal = & .\test\Test-CallFail.ps1 @TFArgs 
$RVal
Write-Host " "

If ($RVal -ne 1) {
       $TFArgs = @{ReturnCD = 1
                   CallNumber = 2}
  $RVal = & .\test\Test-CallFail.ps1 @TFArgs
  $Rval
}
```

The called program looks like this:

```
Param (
  [INt] $ReturnCd,
  [Int] $CallNumber
)

Write-Host "Call Number: $CallNumber"
"$ReturnCd"
```

So if the first call has a ReturnCD of 0. i.e. success the output will look like this:

```
Call Number: 1
0

Call Number: 2
1
```

If you change the ReturnCD to 1, i.e. failed it looks like this:

```
Call Number: 1
1
```

The second call was not made.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

$Result = Invoke-Expression "$worker1 $args" -ErrorAction Stop

## other stuff in main script

if ($Result)
{
  $worker2 = "./workers/worker2.ps1"
  Invoke-Expression "$worker2 $args" -ErrorAction Stop
}

Comment: The OP has indicated that the scripts signal failure via `exit 1`, not via their _output_. On a general note: please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 0):

After a few attempts I've found simple way:

```
# other stuff in main script
& ./workers/worker1.ps1 -PARAM1 "$VAR1" -PARAM2 "$VAR2"
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
    Write-Output "worker1 has failed"
    exit 1
} else {
    Write-Output "worker1 has completed"
}
# other stuff in main script
& ./workers/worker2.ps1
```